# How to download a report as a CSV directly from Salesforce Lightning?

Tags: python, salesforce, salesforce-lightning

I am creating a Python script for downloading a report from Salesforce as a CSV.

My script is working perfectly fine for Salesforce Classic. However, I need to get it working for Lightning Experience. I'm using the simple-salesforce Python package to access our org. For SF Classic I enter a link that is structured like this: https://my-company.my.salesforce.com/my_report_id?view=d&snip&export=1&enc=UTF-8&xf=csv

The script is basically like this:

```py
from simple-salesforce import Salesforce
import requests
import pandas as pd
import csv
from io import StringIO

sf = Salesforce(username="my_username", password="my_password",
                security_token="my_token")
sf_org = "https://my_company.my.salesforce.com/"
report_id = "0000" # Some report id

sf_report_loc = "{0}{1}?view=d&snip&export=1&enc=UTF-8&xf=csv".format(sf_org, report_id)

response = requests.get(sf_report_loc, headers=sf.headers, cookies={"sid": sf.session_id})
new_report = response.content.decode("utf-8")
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(new_report)) # Save the report to a DataFrame.
```

Whenever I switch to Lightning, the link is invalid and I get redirected. Is there a way to make this work in Lightning?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try with `isdtp` parameter. In classic it was used to force view pages without sidebar or header, for example add `isdtp=vw` to a random page and see what happens.

`https://my_company.my.salesforce.com/00O.....?isdtp=p1&export=1&enc=UTF-8&xf=csv` ?

(no idea what's 'p1' but that's what I see in Chrome's download history as part of the report's source URL)

Comment: Awesome! I checked the link you provided me. It now works for Lightning. But what's even better, it still works for Classic as well! Thank you very much.

Comment: Glad you got it to work again! Just remember this is UI hacking, not a real API so they can break it anytime (again). If you have some free time - the "more proper" way to fetch this report would be Analytics API: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_analytics.meta/api_analytics/sforce_analytics_rest_api_get_reportdata.htm

Comment: Analytics (00OR*) is not the same thing as Reports (00O6*); now my problem is that I only get a header of the report, without the details, any ideas? Chrome's download history has just isdtp in the querystring, the rest is probably POSTed but I struggle to catch it from lightning :(

Comment: Don't have an org with Wave/Tableau connected handy, sorry. Consider posting @ https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.reports_filter_url.htm&type=5 does anything clever happen if you click that "Share" button they mention?